# Read data from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get data from a SQL Server database and return data (all data) based on a query as follows:

```
        public async Task<List<PersonEntity>> GetDataAsync()
        {
            var allUsers = new List<PersonEntity>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select* from <TABLE> <WHERE>", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var a = new PersonEntity { 
                        LocationAreaCode = reader.GetString(0),
                        PersonStatusCode = reader.GetString(1),
                        PersonStatusDesc = reader.GetString(2)                        
                    };
                    allUsers.Add(a);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // no data found
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();            
            return allUsers;
        }
```

Is there a better way (in terms of performance) to read all data (**values from all the columns**) matching the query and ***return*** the data from this function?

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest you look at e.g. [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) and avoid writing all this boring, annoying "glue code" yourself - let Dapper handle all that for you and concentrate on the real business value in your code

Comment: I second that - learn dapper - it is trivially easy to use and learn, is very lightweight, and makes everything easier when using C# and SQL Server. You'll never go back to doing it the hard way. If you use C# and SQL Server, there is no better tool.

Comment: Look at the documentation for IDataReader and IDataRecord. `0` is the column index. Knowing that, you can get the data from the second column at index `1`, etc. I don't know how many columns you have since you used `*` but I guess you'd know. While I agree that abstractions like Dapper are advantageous it would not hurt to know a little bit about ADO.NET itself.

Comment: Stay away from 'SELECT *'.  This can backfire.    What if your table has two columns now, but someone changes the table to have 200 columns, with large amounts of data (varbinary, text)?  This will hurt performance by selecting data that you don't need, or require you to go back and fix your low-performing code.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use ADO.net SqlDataAdapter Class

```
var ds = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
   

   
    command.CommandText = "Select * from <table-name> where location = 'US'";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

     }
```

Comment: Why do they _need_ to use an adapter?  What is `SqlDataAdapter` doing that they couldn't do themselves with `SqlDataReader`?  What if they don't want to return their results as a `DataSet`/`DataTable`?